# getting error for Macbook Air M1 "Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider, fallback to system defaults

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-webflux, netty, apple-m1

ERROR 2481 --- [API-GATEWAY] [ender@6e0b642c}] i.n.r.d.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders  : Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider, fallback to system defaults. This may result in incorrect DNS resolutions on MacOS. Check whether you have a dependency on 'io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos'. Use DEBUG level to see the full stack: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtOHq.png)

Getting the above error when i am using Spring Reactive Web dependancy on my spring boot microservice to create API-GATEWAY. I am using it on Macbook air M1 laptop.

tried adding the following dependancy and other possible solutions like creating profile but it is not fixing my issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
  <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Please suggest me, how i can resolve this issue.